# Non-generic constructor in generic class in java

Tags: java, generics, graph-theory

I'm creating an a Graph-class to represent undirected graphs. In the end it will be able to read and parse from files (with for example Newick or DOT format), so ideally the names of the vertices in the graphs should be either strings or integers, with the use of generics as a comfortable solution.

The class is specified to have a constructor that takes an integer as number of vertices and a double for the probability to create an edge between any two nodes. It should then create a randomized graph from that information, and here I run into problems with the generics. The graph is represented with an adjacency list, that need to be "forced" to take integers as the name of the vertices. Is it possible to have one non-generic constructor in this generic class in Java?

One solution is to skip the generics fully and go for string names of nodes only, but I'm a bit interested in if it is possible to do or not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But I wouldn't recommend to do that. Here is why:

Short answer:

`MyGeneric mg = new MyGeneric();`
is the same, as
`MyGeneric<Object> mg = new MyGeneric<>();`

Long answer:

```
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    a.add("somestring");
    a.add(15);
    a.add(new ArrayList());
    a.add(new Button());

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(a.get(i).getClass());
    }
```

output:

class java.lang.String

class java.lang.Integer

class java.util.ArrayList

class java.awt.Button

Now you can put anything to it. this is because it sets the type automatically to Object. In order to use e.g. methods of class String on the object you need to cast it first to String.

If you set the type of array list to e.g. String (`ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();`), you won't be permitted to put just anything, that extends Obejct (which means- literally just anything) to your container.